# Magento 2.1 paypal express requires customer login

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, paypal-express, mini-cart

I'm trying to configure PayPal express checkout in Magento 2.1.8 unfortunately without success. Every time I try to checkout out from the minicart with PayPal express checkout Magento asks me to login in. In my understanding it should get all information from PayPal, isn't it?

I'm also not able to login to manager.paypal.com getting the error message:
*Error: This feature is currently not available for your account. We are working to bring this feature to you soon.*

Tried to configure it according to:
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html

Any idea/help welcomed. If you need further information let me know ...

best

/David